# Run a MATLAB routine when a file is added to a folder

Tags: windows, scripting, matlab, automation, wmi

I am currently working on a project where a file, or files, could be dumped to one of several locations on a server. I have a routine set up in MATLAB which processes the files quite nicely and I would like to automate this so that I don't have to waste any more of my time processing the files.

I found a WMI script (from ScriptingGuy [Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/11/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-script-any-time-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder.aspx)) that behaves in a way that works for me, except I don't know enough about WMI to alter it to my purposes.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE " _
    & "Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
    & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

I tried using the command line tools for MATLAB replacing the Wscript.Echo line

```
matlab -automation -r someRoutine(varargin)
```

which failed miserably.

Could someone please give me some guidance on properly calling MATLAB from WMI and changing the target directory to multiple directories on the server?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `WScript.Shell` and the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx) method:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
objShell.Run "matlab -automation -r someRoutine(varargin)"
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx) describes optional parameters that allow you to control how the process that is created is shown, and whether or not you wait for it to complete.